# I don't know how delete python2 in mac?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I used visual studio in mac air and I install python3.8.5 but already mac has python2
So I can't use python3.8 in visual studio..
I don't know how delete python2 in mac?
plz give me some tips..

Comment: Don’t delete python2 on your Mac. Learn how to tell vs code which python to use. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470563/how-do-you-get-visual-studio-code-to-use-different-python-interpreter

Comment: Don't delete your system python.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default shell in use selection a new one,  you can choose default shell in execution when using visual studio code:

[image]

You can customize your shell execution selecting the `Select default shell`, after you can select your current path to python3.

To discover where is your default python3 installation you can run the command:

```
which python3
#/usr/local/bin/python3
```

After that you can configure the default python3 path in your visual studio instance.
just select the terminal and override the  `terminal.integrated.shell.osx`: environment variable.