# How to select python interpreter on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

I have some issues about selecting python interpreter... I select my python.exe but doesnt work I m getting crazy I did everything searching on the net but anything can do.

[image: select python interpereter]

[image: enviroment]

[image: vs]

[image: python]

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: @AndiDomi doesnt anything select but doenst change on vs code

Comment: for me the python path is just `python`
Like:
`"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "python"`

Comment: I try too now but isnt work yet

Comment: what does the status line tell you

Comment: The directories about Python added to **PATH** should be two: `/.../python39; /.../python39/Scripts/`. After setting the path, reload the window and re-select python interpreter to have a try. Also, `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"` should be specified to python.exe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get Visual Studio Code to use different Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470563/how-do-you-get-visual-studio-code-to-use-different-python-interpreter)