# Cannot execute runserver in Django VScode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode to learn Django. I initially set up a virtual environment with Python 3.9. When I type

```
python
```

in Mac's terminal. It displays "python3.9" without any issue.

However, when I type the same command in the terminal embeded in VScode. It shows python2.7 as below. Is it a problem of VScode or the settings?

[image]

I am learning Django right now and when I run the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It shows the error as below. I doubt that two issues were related, but cannot resolve it. Could anyone help me out? Tons of thanks.

```
  File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried command "python3" in VScode's terminal. It shows:

```
(web_programming) @Huans-MacBook-Pro wiki % python3
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to change the Python Intrepreter in VSCode to point to Python 3.9 and see if the `runserver` error disappears.

See this answer: [How do you get Visual Studio Code to use different Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470563/how-do-you-get-visual-studio-code-to-use-different-python-interpreter)

Comment: This is a wired problem. I restarted VScode and found the problem disappeared...Anyway, thanks all the same.